# Chosen select an option by default with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have one select box with options and I am using jQuery "Chosen" on a Zend View. This plugin is working fine.

```
Javascript:
$('#select_type').chosen();
```

My problem is I need to select one of the options when the page loads depending on what the value of type_id is. I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('select_type').value = '<?=$this->type_id?>';
```

This changes its value but the option is not selected in the JQuery chosen.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT: The option successfully changes by doing what I have mentioned above but it does not update/change the selected element in jQuery "chosen" plugin. My question is about updating the selected value for jQuery Chosen not the HTML SELECT (which I have done successfully). [Here is a link to jQuery Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Comment: Isn't this two separate problems? The jQuery provided has nothing to do with the value, and vice versa.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### Update list with JS

After you run:

```
document.getElementById('select_type').value = '<?=$this->type_id?>';
```

#### For Chosen version 1 and above (newer)

You should call:

```
$('#select_type').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Taken from the [Chosen documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events):

> Updating Chosen Dynamically
>
> If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "chosen:updated" event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated content.
>
> `$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");`

See [the change log](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/tag/1.0.0) for the announcement of this API change.

#### For Chosen versions below 1 (older)

You should call:

```
$('#select_type').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

Taken from the [Chosen documentation](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/):

> Updating Chosen Dynamically
>
> If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen
>   to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "liszt:updated"
>   event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated
>   content.
>
> - **jQuery Version**: `$("#form_field").trigger("liszt:updated");`
> - **Prototype Version**: `Event.fire($("form_field"), "liszt:updated");`

### Set the value before calling Chosen

Instead of doing this from JS why don't you just set the selected option in the HTML before calling the Chosen plugin with JavaScript? You are setting the value from a piece of PHP so I don't see why this couldn't be done.

Comment: This is great!  I needed to make a `change()` operate on the DOM, but have the `<select>` revert back to normal.  If your first option is `<option value></option>` like in the documentation, you can put this at the end of the `change()` binding to reset the select menu: `$(this).val(""); $(this).trigger("liszt:updated")`

Comment: Starting with version 1.0 which the trigger is now "chosen:updated". See http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events

Comment: @Tony thank you for mentioning that. I have updated my answer to reflect these changes to their API.

Answer (score 7):

You can just set the correct elements with the attribute selected like so:

```
<select name="teams[]" data-placeholder="Chose an option:" 
        class="chzn-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option selected="selected">Dallas Cowboys</option>
    <option selected="selected">New York Giants</option>
    <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
    <option>Washington Redskins</option>
</select>
```

Chosen will take care to initialize itself and show the two pre-selected choices.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#select_type").val(<?=$this->type_id?>).trigger('change');

$('#select_type').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#select_type').val('<?=$this->type_id;?>'); // Select the value before .chosen();
$('#select_type').chosen();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select_type').val('<?=$this->type_id?>');
```

try it

Comment: Thanks yapingchen but I know how to set an option selected I needed selection in the plugin i mentioned above

Comment: $('#select_type').val('<?=$this->type_id?>');

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
$("#choen-presentacion").val(value.id_presentacion).trigger('chosen:updated')
```